# Joins of two table with Lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

I am new to Lambda expression. I want a result from combination of two tables with where clause in lambda Expression , query runs fine but how to get result in variable after processing query??

```
var Rental = db.AUCDATA_COUPONS.Join(db.AUCDATA_TENORS,
                     c => c.AUCDT_ID,
                     o => o.AUCDT_ID,
                     (c, o) => new { c, o })
               .Where(x => x.o.PRODUCT_ID == "SUKUK" && x.o.ISSUE_DATE == Convert.ToDateTime("02-MAR-12") && x.o.TENOR_ID == "03Y"
                   && x.c.AUCDT_ID == x.o.AUCDT_ID && x.c.COUPON_NXTDT == Convert.ToDateTime("21-NOV-15"))
              .Select(x => x.c.RENTAL_RATE);
```

Answer (score 2):

`db.AUCDATA_COUPONS` is an `IQueryable<T>` (where `T` is the type of the class representing the table). The *extension methods* you use (like `Join`, `Where` and `Select`) take this `IQueryable<T>` and return a new `IQueryable<T>`.

The last `Select` returns an `IQueryable<int>` (or `double` depending of the type of `RENTAL_RATE`). The actual query (the lambdas) are *only executed when you iterate* through that `IQueryable`. You can do that with `foreach`

```
foreach(var rentalRate in Rental)
```

Maybe a better way is to convert the result to a list or array. This way you would execute the query only once and not again and again with every `foreach` you execute:

```
var list = Rental.ToList(); // results in an List<int>
// or
var array = Rental.ToArray(); // results in an int[]
```

---

Note that you'll probably need to change your datetime comparisons to

```
x.o.ISSUE_DATE.Date == new DateTime(2012,3,2)
```

and

```
x.c.COUPON_NXTDT.Date == new DateTime(2015,11,21)
```

for the query to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but Problem not solve, after using .tolist() there is an errors occurs,

Comment: select c.rental_rate from aucdata_coupons c ,aucdata_tenors t where t.product_id='SUKUK' and trunc(t.issue_date) = '02-MAR-12' and t.tenor_id = '03Y' and t.aucdt_id = c.aucdt_id and c.coupon_nxtdt = '21-NOV-15'     , please convert it into lambda expression .????

Comment: @UmairIkhtiar Your query actually seems correct. You did not tell us any problem. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). _What_ error occurs? You'll probably need to change your datetime comparisons to `x.o.ISSUE_DATE.Date == new DateTime(2012,3,2)` and `x.c.COUPON_NXTDT.Date == new DateTime(2015,11,21)`

Comment: Thanks , yes this was the problem. query run fine and show result,

Answer (score 1):

You already have the results in the variable. But, depending on what you want to do with them, you can add `.ToArray()` or `.ToList()` after `.Select(...)`.

Comment: Why? You don't need to convert the results to an array to iterate over them. The result of the query is essentially the same as any other IEnumerable<T> (apart from the transparent delayed execution)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - The OP asked to get the results into a variable - it's a vague request, but I think this answer is valid.

Comment: @Enigmativity the OP already has the results in a variable. There is no need to convert to an array to use them. `ToArray` *converts* the result, just like `ToList` or `ToList` would do. `AsEnumerable` would be enough to eagerly load the results. None of these is needed though to access the data

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I agree with that. It may be that the OP just wants to ensure the query is executed at that particular point in the code. Like I said he's vague about what he wants.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree too. Maybe he just wants to see the results by inspecting the variable, IDK.